# fotorama with change of image on hover in thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fotorama

I use jquery gallery fotorama (http://fotorama.io) for my website, I try to implement a change of image with mouse hover on the thumbnails, like this http://www.homeaway.co.uk/p3530150#photos gallery.

I read the API documentation and search for any solution but I dont have idea.

thanks for your help

JH

Comment: Please give us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually, you want lower opacity on load, and higher on hover, if i understand you correctly? Solve it via simple css...

Comment: @nevermind not, when I put the mouse cursor on the thumbnail the image of the gallery change.

Please see this URL:

http://www.homeaway.co.uk/p3530150#photos 

thanks

Comment: @user3304983, sorry, but i don't see image change on hover here. I am using firefox (image is not changed in chrome, too)...p.s. find some other script, event change in fotorama could be very tricky...

Comment: Hi @nevermind please goto this title "SPECIAL OFFER!!! MODERN 2 BEDROOM SPACIOUS APT 4M WALK ANGEL TUBE CENTRAL LONDON" on http://www.homeaway.co.uk/p3530150#photos

and see the galery on top, this galery change with hover on the thumb.

how to make this with fotorama, in this page the galery is implemented with jcarousel (jquery plugin)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.fotorama__nav__frame', function () {
  var $fotoramaDiv = $(this).parents('.fotorama'),
      fotoramaApi = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');
  fotoramaApi.show({
    index: $('.fotorama__nav__frame', $fotoramaDiv).index(this)
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evvx5ynL/)**